# PostgreSQL array_agg returns null if first param is null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to aggregate data into 1 field.
So I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
t.userId,
array_agg(t.column1 || ';' || t.column2) as aggregated        
FROM
mytable t
GROUP BY
t.userId
```

However if t.column1 is null, and t.column2 is not null, then i get a NULL returned. I would like to return something like this:

> column1;column2 OR null;column2 OR column1;null

How could I do this with array_agg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not array_agg, that does that but the `||` operator. It yields null if any of the elements is null. To avoid that, use

```
concat_ws(';', t.column1, t.column2)
```

It essentially treats `null` values as empty strings.

If you want an explicit `null` string, you can use:

```
coalesce(t.column1,'null')|| ';' ||coalesce(t.column2, 'null')
```

Comment: Ah cool thanks! thats what i need.